# calling stored procedure with cursor and out parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

I  have the following stored procedure

```
CREATE OR Replace  PROCEDURE sprocvPOP_GetvemployeeByFilter
  (TheFilter   varchar2,
   TheOrder     varchar2,
   PageOrder    int,
   ItemsPerPage int,
   TheCount out  number,
   cur out  sys_refcursor)as  
begin 
........
end
```

I want to call this procedure, and print cur parameter  and the count parameter values because they are out variables.

I tried using the following syntax in SQL Developer

```
set serveroutput on 
var rc refcursor;
declare
mycount number(19);
begin
execute sprocvPOP_GetvemployeeByFilter (NULL,NULL,1,10,mycount,:rc);
print rc;
dbms_output.put_line(mycount);
end;
```

but I got the error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RC" when expecting one of the following:
>      := . ( @ % ;
>   The symbol ":=" was substituted for "RC" to continue.

How can I execute this procedure and print out parameters in SQL Developer?

Comment: `print rc` is a SQL*Plus command, so it needs to be outside the PL/SQL block (after the `end;`).

Comment: iam using sql developer so how can i call this procedure ?

Comment: i put print rc ; after end; but i'm still getting errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question, `print rc` is a SQL*Plus command, so it needs to be outside the PL/SQL block. `execute` is also a SQL*Plus command and is not used in PL/SQL. So your code should look like this:

```
set serveroutput on 
var rc refcursor;
declare
  mycount number(19);
begin
  sprocvPOP_GetvemployeeByFilter (NULL,NULL,1,10,mycount,:rc);
  dbms_output.put_line(mycount);
end;
/
print rc;
```

However, it turns out you are using SQL Developer not SQL*Plus client to run your code. Not many  SQL*Plus commands are natively supported in SQL Developer. [The list is here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/intro.htm#CHDIJIEF)

The latest versions of the tool come with a Command Line interface  which is very neat. [Find out more](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/07/sql-developer-4-0-and-the-command-line-interface-cli/).

Alternatively, use the built-in Run PL/SQL functionality as described [in this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e12152/tut_library.htm#RPTUG20700)